# Find the particular solution of, $y=Ce^{-2x}+De^{-3x}+\cos(x)+\sin(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Where, $y = 1$, $dy/dx = 0$ when $x = 0$.

I've tried using simultaneous equations but keep getting $0$ as an answer for both constants, not sure how else to proceed.

Comment: Literally just edited :D, i think my skepticism is rooted in the fact that it appears too good to be true

Comment: I get that $C=-1$ and $D=1$. If both $C=0$ and $D=0$, then $y=\cos(x)+\sin(x)$, and $y'=-\sin(x)+\cos(x)$, so $y'(0)=1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @projectilemotion: yep, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

From the initial conditions,

$$\begin{cases}1=C+D+1,
\\0=-2C-3D+1.\end{cases}$$

$C=D=0$ is obviously not a solution.